# Connecting to remote services from multiple threaded requests

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, libmemcached

I have a boost asio application with many threads, similar to a web server, handling hundreds of concurrent requests.  Every request will need to make calls to both memcached and redis (via libmemcached and redispp respectively).  Is the best practice in this situation to make a separate connection to both redis and memcached from each thread (effectively tripling the open sockets on the server, three per request)?  Or is there a way for me to build a static object, with a single memcached/redis connection, and allow all threads to share that single connection?  I'm a bit confused when it comes to the thread safety of something like this, and everything needs to be asynchronous between the threads, but blocking for each thread's individual request (so each thread has a linear progression, but many threads can be in different places in their own progression at any given time).  Does that make sense?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since memcached have syncronous protocol you should not write next request before you got answer to prevous. So, no other thread can chat in same memcached connection. I'd prefer to make thread-local connection if you work with it in "blocking" mode.

Or you can make it work in "async" manner: make pool of connections, pick a connection from it (and lock it). After request is done, return it to pool.

Also, you can make a request queue and process it in special thread(s) (using multigets and callbacks).